# Filtering integers from list of list in OCaml

Tags: list, int, ocaml

I am trying to write a function that filters positive integers from a list of list of integers, returning a list of only negative integers.

For example, if I have a list of list such as [[-1; 1]; [1]; [-1;-1]] it would return [[-1]; []; [-1;-1]].

I tried to use filter and transform functions, which was in my textbook.

```
let rec transform (f:'a -> 'b) (l:'a list) : 'b list =
begin match l with
| [] -> []
| x::tl -> (f x)::(transform f tl)
end
```

and for filter, I had previously written:

```
let rec filter (pred: 'a -> bool) (l: 'a list) : 'a list =
  begin match l with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: tl -> if pred x then x :: (filter pred tl) else filter pred tl
  end
```

So, using these, I wrote

```
let filter_negatives (l: int list list) : int list list = 
  transform (fun l -> (filter(fun i -> i<0)) + l) [] l
```

but I'm still having trouble fully understanding anonymous functions, and I'm getting error messages which I don't know what to make of.

> This function has type ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
>          It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For what it's worth this `transform` function is more commonly called `map`.)

The error message is telling you a simple, true fact. The `transform` function takes two arguments: a function and a list. You're giving it 3 arguments. So something must be wrong.

The transformation you want to happen to each element of the list is a filtering. So, if you remove the `+` (which really doesn't make any sense) from your transforming function you have something very close to what you want.

Possibly you just need to remove the `[]` from the arguments of `transform`. It's not clear (to me) why it's there.

Comment: Looks like something you would have in a tail recursive transform, the accumulator of the result. But here the transform isn't made tail recursive and only has 2 arguments. I agree that the `[]` shouldn't be there.